# Correct way to enable a custom target

Tags: linux, systemd

(I've cross posted this question on the [systemd github](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/12418))

I have two daemons, one is a.service, which depends on an instance of b@.service.  I will not necessarily know what the name of the b@.service instance is when writing the unit file, but a.service will definitely depend on one of those instances being running.

My solution is to create an b.target, of which b@.service contains `PartOf=a.target` and `WantedBy=a.target`.

I want b.target to be started any time graphical.target is started, so ideally I want b.target to be `WantedBy=graphical.target`.  a.service should also be `WantedBy=graphical.target`, but also needs to be `Requisite=b.target` and `After=b.target` (It should not start b.target, and should fail if b.target is not started).

```
 [  a.service   ]
|                |
|   Depends on   |  
v                v     
 [  b.target    ]   <--is part of--[b@x.service]
|                |
|   Should be    |
|   started by   |
v                v
[graphical.target]
```

The [systemd.target documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html) specifies that targets are installed with a `Requires=` clause, but if I do that, it creates a dependency loop, when really I want it to be RequiredBy or WantedBy graphical.target, and not the other way around.

This works if, and only if, I add an [Install] section with `WantedBy=graphical.target` to b.target.  The documentation does not seem to indicate this should be done, but it works - on startup, graphical.target correctly starts up b.target, which starts up b@x.service, and graphical.target also starts a.service, which correctly waits for b@x.service to start.

Is this the correct way to handle a service depending on an instanced service, and is this the correct way to handle dependencies between targets?  Just because something works does not necessarily mean it is the correct way to do it, and systemd in particular has a "systemd way" of doing things that tends to relieve headaches down the road if that "systemd way" is followed.